# Oracle 11g insert + update results in lock

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, locking

I'm working wiht an oracle 11g database and I'am having lock problems.

I have 2 sessions and I'm executing as follows:

- (Session 1) INSERT into table1 with a known id
- (Session 2) INSERT into table1 with another known id => No lock
- (Session 1) UPDATE from table1 where id = id inserted in the first step => **Lock**

In both store procedures (insert and update) I include the following clause:

**LOCK TABLE table1 IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;**

I think that the problem is that oracle is making a table lock in the insert, or it is just not getting wich is the row I'm trying to update, although, isn`t that the objetive of row level table lock??

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

I atach my scripts:

**CRETE TABLE**

```
    CREATE TABLE ARGOXP.T_AREA
    (
      ARE_ID      INTEGER,
      ARE_NOMBRE  VARCHAR2(80 BYTE)                 NOT NULL,
      ARE_DESCRI  VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
      ARE_ACTIVO  NUMBER(1)                         NOT NULL
    )
    TABLESPACE ARGOXP
    PCTUSED    0
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                PCTINCREASE      0
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
               )
    LOGGING 
    NOCOMPRESS 
    NOCACHE
    NOPARALLEL
    MONITORING;



CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ARGOXP.PK_T_AREA ON ARGOXP.T_AREA
(ARE_ID)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE ARGOXP
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
NOPARALLEL;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ARGOXP.UK_ARE_NOMBRE ON ARGOXP.T_AREA
(ARE_NOMBRE)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE ARGOXP
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
NOPARALLEL;


ALTER TABLE ARGOXP.T_AREA ADD (
  CONSTRAINT PK_T_AREA
 PRIMARY KEY
 (ARE_ID)
    USING INDEX 
    TABLESPACE ARGOXP
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   2
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                PCTINCREASE      0
               ),
  CONSTRAINT UK_ARE_NOMBRE
 UNIQUE (ARE_NOMBRE)
    USING INDEX 
    TABLESPACE ARGOXP
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   2
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL    

  64K
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
           ));
```

**STORE PROCEDURES**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ARGOXP."P_T_AREA_I_PK" 
(
pARE_ID T_AREA.ARE_ID%TYPE,
pARE_NOMBRE T_AREA.ARE_NOMBRE%TYPE,
pARE_DESCRI T_AREA.ARE_DESCRI%TYPE := NULL,
pARE_ACTIVO T_AREA.ARE_ACTIVO%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
LOCK TABLE T_AREA IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;

  INSERT INTO T_AREA
    ( ARE_ID,
      ARE_NOMBRE,
      ARE_DESCRI,
      ARE_ACTIVO
    )
  VALUES
    ( pARE_ID,
      pARE_NOMBRE,
      pARE_DESCRI,
      pARE_ACTIVO
    );
END;
/



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ARGOXP."P_T_AREA_U_PK" 
(
pARE_ID T_AREA.ARE_ID%TYPE,
pARE_NOMBRE T_AREA.ARE_NOMBRE%TYPE,
pARE_DESCRI T_AREA.ARE_DESCRI%TYPE := NULL,
pARE_ACTIVO T_AREA.ARE_ACTIVO%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
LOCK TABLE T_AREA IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;

  UPDATE
    T_AREA
  SET
    ARE_ID = pARE_ID,
      ARE_NOMBRE = pARE_NOMBRE,
      ARE_DESCRI = pARE_DESCRI,
      ARE_ACTIVO = pARE_ACTIVO
  WHERE
    ARE_ID = pARE_ID
;
END;
/
```

*LATEST UPDATES*

We have been working hard with this issue this last days, and we would like to share the latest updates. We execute the inserts and updates in the 2 sessions without using stored procedures, and this results in non locks. After that, we created new stored procedures for the insert and the update, without parameters. We just include the stored procedure definition and the script to execute the insert or the update. This resulted in non lock too! But when we call the stored procedure with the parameters, we get the locks.

I atach the execution steps followed to get the locks:

(FIRST)
In session 1:

```
DECLARE 
  PARE_ID NUMBER;
  PARE_NOMBRE VARCHAR2(80);
  PARE_DESCRI VARCHAR2(1000);
  PARE_ACTIVO NUMBER;

BEGIN 
  PARE_ID := 70;
  PARE_NOMBRE := '70';
  PARE_DESCRI := '70';
  PARE_ACTIVO := 1;

  ARGOXP.P_T_AREA_I_PK ( PARE_ID, PARE_NOMBRE, PARE_DESCRI, PARE_ACTIVO );
END;
```

(SECOND)
In session 2

```
DECLARE 
  PARE_ID NUMBER;
  PARE_NOMBRE VARCHAR2(80);
  PARE_DESCRI VARCHAR2(1000);
  PARE_ACTIVO NUMBER;

BEGIN 
  PARE_ID := 71;
  PARE_NOMBRE := '71';
  PARE_DESCRI := '71';
  PARE_ACTIVO := 1;

  ARGOXP.P_T_AREA_I_PK ( PARE_ID, PARE_NOMBRE, PARE_DESCRI, PARE_ACTIVO );
END;
```

(THIRD) In session 2

```
DECLARE 
  PARE_ID NUMBER;
  PARE_NOMBRE VARCHAR2(80);
  PARE_DESCRI VARCHAR2(1000);
  PARE_ACTIVO NUMBER;

BEGIN 
  PARE_ID := 1;
  PARE_NOMBRE := 'update number 1';
  PARE_DESCRI := 'update number 2';
  PARE_ACTIVO := 1;

  ARGOXP.P_T_AREA_U_PK ( PARE_ID, PARE_NOMBRE, PARE_DESCRI, PARE_ACTIVO );
END;
```

We get the locks in this step.

We also execute the following query with the sysdba user:

```
SELECT b.OBJECT_NAME, c.ROW_WAIT_OBJ#,c.ROW_WAIT_FILE#,c.ROW_WAIT_BLOCK#,c.ROW_WAIT_ROW#
   FROM v$locked_object a, dba_objects b, v$session c    
WHERE a.object_id = b.object_id    
    AND a.SESSION_ID = c.sid(+);
```

getting the following results:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you're having. Is your update locking something you don't expect, or getting an error? When - if at all - do you unlock, or commit/rollback? Showing your stored procedures (or at least a demo that lets us replicate and understand) might be useful.

Comment: Take out the `lock table` statement.  There is virtually never a reason to issue an explicit `lock table` statement.  Just let Oracle handle row-level locking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! tacking out lock table didnt resolve the problem.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the update is locking the entire table, I am expecting to find locked only the just inserted row. Thanks!

Comment: The most probale explanation is that you are trying to update a record that has a pending (not commitd) chnages from the othe session. For diagnostic see eg. [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35739/when-a-record-is-locked-in-oracle-can-we-know-which-record-is-locked)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I'm executing an insert in the session 1 with the id 50, then, in the session 2, I insert the record with id 51. There is no problem up to here, but then, when I want to update the record id = 1 (i.e), I get the query locked and that is what I'm traing to avoid. I cant figure out why is this last update hanging, because I'm updating a record that was in the table before, so it is not the record inserted by the other transaction.

Comment: SFSG, my point was get a third session and diagnose the cause of the block. You will see something unexpected, because replaying you scenario with insert and update works - no lock. Good luck.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber, thank you very much! I have been working with that queries before, but I am not an expert so it is difucult for me to figure out the problem. I will continue analysing it! The last thing I have done, is executing directly the query (insert into... , update table ...) in the database without using the Store Procedures, and it works! so the problem is in the stored procedures, but I cant see nothing extrange in them

Comment: What values do you use for `pARE_NOMBRE`? Does update try to set `ARE_NOMBRE` to the same value as inserted by Session 2?

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin, thanks for your answer. We have an unique contraint set in the ARE_NOMBRE field, so we are updating with different values.

Comment: I have update the question with "latest update" section. thanks for all!

Comment: Would you be so kind to update the question with some example of proc parameters which results in locking session?

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin I have updated the question with the procedures exection data.

Comment: You insert record with `id = 71` but update with `id = 1`?

Comment: Yes, I insert the id 70 and the id 71, and I update the id 1 that was previously inserted in the database. The table should not be locked by the inserts. It should only be locked the inserted rows in the table, so i should be able to update the row with id=1.

Comment: Inserts do not lock entire table. But uncommitted inserts lock inserted _values_ for every unique column.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. As you can see, we are updating the values respeting the unique constraint. Also, if we call the queries directly (insert or update without calling an stored procedure), or if we create a new store procedure without parameters, we have no locks. It is very strange, and it seems that is related with the parameters defined in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem. We have another table, TABLE_2, that has a reference to the table T_AREA (Foreign Key field called AREA_ID). When we have a foreign key but we dont have an index in that table, oracle throws an automatic lock to the entire table.

So, the solution is to add an index in TABLE_2 for the FK field (ARE_ID in this case)